# Using dynamic memory in the proper scope

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I felt that it is a good practice to use `new` within the same scope `delete` should be used. It is much easier to keep track of memory. For example, suppose I have:

```
class Obj;

Obj* create() {
    Obj* object = new Obj();
    // do a bunch of messy work with object
    return object;
}

int main() {
    Obj* o = create();
}
```

The issue with the code above is that it is not immediately obvious that `o` needs to be freed. So instead, I would prefer:

```
int main() {
    Obj* o = new Obj();
    // do a bunch of messy work with o
}
```

This way, I would remember to `delete` `o`. However, this too is causing me issues. I'm working on a larger project at the moment and my `main()` is beginning to look large and messy due to a bunch of statements that can easily be grouped together within a single function.

So which practice should I use when working on larger projects (or any sized project for that matter) i.e, should I use `new` within `main()` to better keep track of memory but pay the price of messier code or should I use `new` within functions to have cleaner code but have a slightly more difficult time manually managing memory?

My apologies if this question is too specific or not as important as I'm making it out to be.

Comment: Two options: Return a value `Obj create();` or return a smart pointer: `std::unique_ptr<Obj> create();`.

Comment: If using C++11 or later you can use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers. It's also often possible to return newly created objects by value and get Return Value Optimization from the compiler, if your reason for returning pointers was based on performance concerns.

Comment: Don't ignore these possibilities: `Obj* o = new Obj(); setup(o); delete o;` and the best one of all: `Obj o; setup(&o); /* cleanup is automatic */`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that passing around pointers makes it difficult to track ownership. If you have access to C++11, you could return an [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to express the intent of passing ownership to the caller. 
If you only have access to C++03 features, the boost library features [boost::unique_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/movelib/unique_ptr.html), too.

Using `std::unique_ptr` `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::weak_ptr` where appropriate would also simplify memory management (prevent mismanagement) when exception handling comes into play.

Using `new` and `delete` expressly has few uses in modern C++ short of writing custom containers, allocators, and other lower-level tasks.

**In short:** Use smart pointers when you can, and manual memory management when you have to.

Comment: This answer is correct, but you shouldn't ignore the option of using a locally-scoped automatic variable and avoiding dynamic allocation altogether.

Answer (score 4):

best practice is to never use `new` directly at all -- use objects that manage the memory for you like `std::string` and `std::vector`, and if you really need pointer-like things, use `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` to make `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` objects...